# How can I combine these two Regex statements into one with String.repalceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I have this string,

`"36635,36635,36635,36635   36635   36635 36635  36635-36635-36635"`

By the end of it I would like

`36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635`

I've managed to achieve this with the below code.

```
String original = "36635,36635,36635,36635   36635   36635 36635  36635-36635-36635";
String justSpaces =  original.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
String oneSpaceMax = justSpaces.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
System.out.printf("Original: %s \n JustSpaces: %s \n oneSpaceMax: %s", original, justSpaces, oneSpaceMax);
```

Output

```
Original: 36635,36635,36635,36635   36635   36635 36635  36635-36635-36635 
JustSpaces: 36635 36635 36635 36635   36635   36635 36635  36635 36635 36635 
oneSpaceMax: 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635 36635
```

How can I combine those two regex statements? I've attempted using the Or `|` operator but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
original = original.replaceAll("\\D+", " ");
```

`\\D+` will match 1 or more non-digit (including spaces) and replacement is just a single space.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH3eJ9/1)